# How to get other control value from UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, custom-cell

I have one doubt that how to get other control's value when we select a row or tap on button while having custom tableViewCell. 
Suppose I have a TableView Cell with a TextField, a Slider and button. Button has action using:

```
btn.tag = indexPath.row;
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Now I can get button on its action method. I need to get textField's value and slider's value on button tap.

The one option is I create a array and store values for these two control in that array and manage this. But I don't think this is correct way to manage it.

Please navigate me to the currect way to get value of UITableViewCell's subview's value.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While creating your textfield and slider, give them a constant tag and then add to cell's contentView

```
textfield.tag= TEXTFIELDTAG; //TEXTFIELDTAG = 100 or any other constant
[cell.contentView addSubview:textfield];
```

and then in your buttonTapped: method

```
-(void)buttonTapped:(id)sender
{

    int row = ((UIButton*)sender).tag;
    NSIndexPath* indexpath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0]; // in case this row in in your first section
    UITableViewCell* cell = [table cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UITextField* textfield = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:TEXTFIELDTAG];
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error when I use that code.  It looks like the definition for the contentview function is: 
@property (nonatomic, readonly, retain) UIView      *contentView;

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you create subviews (button , text field etc. ) for your `UITableViewCell` don't forget to **tagged** them.

```
myTextField.tag = 0;
myTextLabel.tag = 1; 
[cell addSubview:myTextField];
[cell addSubview:myTextLabel];
```

Once you tagged, you could access them using below method.

```
- (UIView *)viewWithTag:(NSInteger)tag
```

When you select,you could get the subviews of your UITableViewCell's by using `ViewWithTag` function of `UIView`.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        UITextField* myTextField = [cell  viewWithTag:0];
        UILabel* myTextLabel     = [cell  viewWithTag:1];
    }
```