# dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier not releasing data

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView that doesn't release its data that it shows once it is scrolled off the screen.

Each table cell needs to display a name, date, and picture.  The first screen-full of cells work correctly upon startup because they haven't been reused.  However once you begin to scroll and a cell gets reused the data being displayed gets stacked on what that cell was storing previously (example: the date will have July 4, 1981 stacked on top of Dec. 15, 1972).

Here's my code:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"";

    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:kTableViewCellIdentifier];

    self.nameArray = @[@"list of names"];
    self.dateArray = @[@"list of dates"];
    self.imageArray = @[@"list of images"];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return  [self.nameArray count];
}


- (UIView *)messageFeed:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIView *feedView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    //...feedView attributes

    UILabel *nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(..., ..., ..., ...)];
    nameLabel.text = self.nameArray[indexPath.row];
    //nameLabel attributes

    UILabel *dateLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(..., ..., ..., ...)];
    dateLabel.text = self.dateArray[indexPath.row];
    //dateLabel attributes

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(..., ..., ..., ...)];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: self.imageArray[indexPath.row]];
    //imageView attributes

    [feedView addSubview:nameLabel];
    [feedView addSubview:dateLabel];
    [feedView addSubview:imageView];

    return feedView;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kTableViewCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    [cell addSubview:[self messageFeed:indexPath]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: You are adding the subviews EVERY time a cell is displayed / re-used even though you have already added them the first time.  This means that you are not replacing the content (merely adding more over the top) and so the images are never released. There are many, many questions on SO covering this topic.  You need to re-factor your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method to only add the views `if cell == nil` or, better yet, just design the cells in IB in the Storyboard or XIB. Do a search and you will find all the info you need. An example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16174358/558933

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best solution but this works for me.  It appears that the cell is not always nil when I need to add UI fields to the cells subview  To fix this I first check to see if any of the cells tags are set.  If not I add all the UI fields back to the cells subview.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath    
{
   UILabel *background;
   UILabel *nameLabel;
   UILabel *dateLabel;
   UIImageView *imageView;

   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kTableViewCellIdentifier];

   if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kTableViewCellIdentifier];
   }

   background = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:1];
   if (!background) {
       cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
       background = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 40.0f)];
       background.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
       background.tag = 1;
      [cell.contentView addSubview:background];

      nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(84.0f, 10.0f, 216.0f, 29.0f)];
      nameLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
      nameLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0f];
      nameLabel.tag = 2;
      [cell.contentView addSubview:nameLabel];

      dateLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(84.0f, 40.0f, 216.0f, 21.0f)];
      dateLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
      dateLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.0f];
      dateLabel.tag = 3;
      [cell.contentView addSubview:dateLabel];

      imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0f, 13.0f, 56.0f, 51.0f)];
      imageView.tag = 4;
      [cell addSubview:imageView];
   } else {
      nameLabel = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:2];
      dateLabel = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:3];
      imageView = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:4];
   }

   nameLabel.text = self.nameArray[indexPath.row];
   dateLabel.text = self.dateArray[indexPath.row];
   imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: self.imageArray[indexPath.row]];

   return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**messageFeed:** allocate view every time in tableview,when cells are re used in tableview feedView added in previous feed view, try this reusable code.

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        NSString *CellIdentifier = @"newFriendCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if(!cell)
       {
       // Configure the cell...
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        UIView *feedView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        feedView.tag=1;
        UILabel *nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(..., ..., ..., ...)];
       nameLabel.tag=2; 

        UILabel *dateLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(..., ..., ..., ...)];
        dateLabel.tag=3;

        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(..., ..., ..., ...)];
       imageView.tag=4;

        [feedView addSubview:nameLabel];
        [feedView addSubview:dateLabel];
        [feedView addSubview:imageView];
        [cell addSubview:feedView];
    }
        UIView *feedView=(UIView*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
        UILabel *nameLabel =(UILabel*)[feedView viewWithTag:2];
        UILabel *dateLabel =(UILabel*)[feedView viewWithTag:3];
       UIImageView *imageView =(UIImageView*)[feedView viewWithTag:4];
        nameLabel.text = self.nameArray[indexPath.row];
        dateLabel.text = self.dateArray[indexPath.row];
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: self.imageArray[indexPath.row]];
        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks  @NANNAV but it didn't work. It told me that feedView is an unused variable and loaded a table with blank cells.

Comment: sorry it's my mistake see my edited ans. i am forget to change cell to feedView.

Comment: @NANNV does this work for you in a project? I tried it in mine and I'm still getting a table with blank cells. Its the right number of cells, their just all blank

Comment: Can you check if you're using `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];` and not `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kTableViewCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];`? The second one always returns a cell so it would never go inside the `if` condition.

Comment: @pacman321, I've tried both....no luck on either.  Both ways I'm still getting a table with the right number of cells but their all empty.

Comment: @pacman321 it's correct way to reuse cell in tableview,if cell not created in table view then only go to inside if condition,otherwise cells are reused in table view.